# Mediatemple: PHP open_basedir doesn't open private folder

Tags: php, mediatemple, open-basedir

On Mediatemple, I have a file in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/private that needs to be included in a PHP script. I've changed vhost.conf, changed /etc/php.ini and no matter what, I still get "failed to open stream: Permission denied".

When I show the open_basedir setting in PHP, using ini_get(), it displays: "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/:/tmp/:/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/private/" yet I still can't open from private.

My include path is also "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/:/tmp/:/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/private/"

Answer (score 0):

Is this grid hosting? If so, check the /var/www/vhosts/config folder for more vhost configs. You're probably being overwritten from there.

Comment: No, it's Dedicated Virtual. I've changed the vhosts for my domains. There's no config dir directly in the vhosts dir.

Comment: I am looking at a dedicated from Media Temple that runs the Plesk control panel. I have addition config files in /var/www/vhosts/<domain name>/conf. Anything in there for you?

Comment: Thanks for your help. It wasn't the vhost.conf after all, but the group that owned the private directory. D'oh.